# A combination of 3 from a list of first 9 integers

Tags: combinatorics

Thanks in advance for what  may seem a trivial school level question but how many triplet combinations  can be made from the first 9 integers?

Put another way if you have the options to pick from below;

A1,A2,A3

B1,B2,B3

C1,C2,C3

and each triplet combination picked must contain one A one B and one C option

Intuition tells me this is just 3^2 = 27 combinations  or is this too simple or do there need to be other conditions met?

Many thanks
KM

Comment: Your two questions aren't the same - in the first case, we can choose any $3$ out of the $9$, whereas in the second case, we're choosing one out of each of $3$ sets of size $3$.

Comment: Also, $3^2\neq 27$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work a general case then apply to your two cases :

If you need the number $m$ of combinaisons of length $n$ from a set of $k$ elements **with replacement** then you have the formula :

$$m = k^n$$

In your first case, $n=3$ and $k=9$, hence :

$$m_1 = 9^3 = 729 $$

In your second case, $n=3$ and $k=3$, hence :

$$m_2 = 3^3 = 27$$